# Looking for a word meaning "timescale"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am sure that I know (or knew) a word that would mean the time it takes for something to occur after setting it in motion.

The closest I can conjure up is "***timescale***" but that is not what I am looking for. "*Duration*" is also close, but duration suggests the act is ongoing, rather than occurring later.

I need a phrase which would look something like:

> refund "X"

and which should explain to a user that their refund can take up to seven days to process. You can see here how "duration" is not appropriate.

Comment: Please give an example sentence that gives some context and in which your proposed word is entered as "X".

Comment: I think that "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is [off topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Name your template in a way that is convenient and meaningful to yourself.

Comment: "refund time" seems ok (compare idioms like runtime, execution time, journey time). "refund timescale" would also fit your scenario, because you're describing the period of time when you're making a refund, and setting out a timescale i.e. what should happen by a certain time. Alternatively, I suggest you look at as many online store websites as possible, to see what terminology they use.